# AIOHTTP: Client example

Tags: python, aiohttp

I have just installed AIOHTTP on my mac

Python 3.10.8

Visual Studio Code Version: 1.72.2

```
Package            Version
------------------ -------
aiodns             3.0.0
aiohttp            3.8.3
aiosignal          1.2.0
async-timeout      4.0.2
attrs              22.1.0
cffi               1.15.1
charset-normalizer 2.1.1
frozenlist         1.3.1
idna               3.4
multidict          6.0.2
pip                22.3
pycares            4.2.2
pycparser          2.21
setuptools         65.5.0
wheel              0.37.1
yarl               1.8.1
```

Ex. code

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def main():

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('http://python.org') as response:

            print("Status:", response.status)
            print("Content-type:", response.headers['content-type'])

            html = await response.text()
            print("Body:", html[:15], "...")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

When I try to run the code above [Client example](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/index.html) I getting lot of errors, this is just a few of them. What do I miss?

```
test.py:15: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 980, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[return-value]  # noqa

raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host python.org:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/955),

```
session = aiohhtp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False))
```

This is something similar to `verify=False` in `requests` library.

Comment: Must be something more, I have added the ex. code in my topic. Is the ex. up-to date with python 3.10.8 ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The [Getting Started Client example](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/index.html) does not work with 3.10....

Switch between 3.9 and 3.10 is easy way to reproduce the error...[image][image]